# Brackets with the same linewidth in ConTeXt

Tags: matrices, context

> I refer to the same situation as @tommsch at [Brackets with the same linewidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467940/brackets-with-the-same-linewidth) but in `ConTeXt` instead of `LaTeX`.

In `ConTeXt` the two first matrices are clean but the third one has the same problem as @tommsch described even if the spacing is far better.

```
\definemathmatrix[bmatrix][left={\left[\,}, right={\,\right]}]

\starttext
    \startformula
        \startbmatrix
            \startbmatrix
                \NC 1 \NC 0 \NC 0 \NR
                \NC 2 \NC 0 \NC 0 \NR
                \NC 1 \NC 0 \NC 0 \NR
            \stopbmatrix
            \NR
            \startbmatrix
                \NC 1 \NC 1 \NC 0 \NR
                \NC 1 \NC 1 \NC 0 \NR
            \stopbmatrix
            \NR
            \startbmatrix
                \NC 1 \NC 2 \NC 1 \NR
            \stopbmatrix
            \NR
        \stopbmatrix
    \stopformula
\stoptext
```

[image: ConTeXt]

Comment: While you can get the desired results with a combination of `natural tables` or `extreme tables` in combination with a `metapost` background I suggest to send your problem to the [ConTeXt mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context). Other mechanism like fractions let you create special layouts with `metapost` which could be an option for this problem.